# Javascript: Replace Last Line In .txt File

Tags: javascript

I wish to open a file and replace the last line. Not the empty last line, the last last with text, forexample;

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

I would like to transform this into

```
Line1
Line2
Last Line
```

Comment: In node.js running on a server? You can't do it in a browser...

Answer (score 1):

With Windows Scripting Host:

```
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("test.txt");
var lines = fh.ReadAll();
fh.Close();

lines = lines.split('\r\n');
lines = lines.slice(0, -2);
lines.push('Last Line');
lines = lines.join('\r\n');

var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("test.txt", true);
fh.Write(lines);
fh.Close();
```